# 2022 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

> **The election is now over! You can read the results [here](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5771/2022-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1)!**

---

The 2022 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase [Completed]
2. Primary phase [Skipped]
3. Election phase [Completed]

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the **[official election page](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election)** for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta – just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).