# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #6](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/6) on English Language Learners has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: David Siegel]

[image: Laurel]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/election/6) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6068207545745408).

Comment: Congratulations and celebrations!

Comment: Congratulation to Laurel and David_Siegel!

Comment: Grats and welcome to the team David and Laurel!!

Comment: Congrats and welcome aboard