# What does that mean? (User was removed)

Tags: support

I see this but my account is not removed, I'm still able to ask questions.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means another user's account was removed. The removal of that account resulted in you getting some rep points back, probably because they'd downvoted something of yours, and those points don't count anymore, so you're getting a notification about why you're getting points.

Long before a user's account is ever removed, especially a regular positive contributor like you, you'll get communication from us about what the problem is, in the hopes that you can stop doing whatever it is. *İnşallah* it will never come to that.

Comment: I got the same message recently,but with a negative rep change, meaning that a removed user had upvoted me on something, and I had now lost those points. Iy happens, and there is nothing to do about it. It does not mean rhat you did anything improper.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation gotube, I hope so (inşallah). David Siegel, I see you're a mod now, and if I'm not mistaken this's new; congratulations!

Comment: @orhan torun  Fairly new yes, thanks. See https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5757/2022-community-moderator-election for the election and a link to the results. Most users need never worry about being removed..

Comment: Note that that they down-voted 3 of your posts might indicate that they had been doing massive down-votes of many people, and that could be the reason they were removed.